# how to use createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2

Tags: android, opencv, object-detection, contour

I am using OpenCV4Android version 3.1.0 and I want to remove the background in each frame taken from the Android Camera. I referred to some posts and what i understood is, since the background should be removed from a non-static
background "Android Camera" i should use `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2`

according to an example, i am using the `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2` as shown in the code below. But at run time, regardless of the changing background in the frame retrieved from the camera, i get mask `fgmask` contains always
a white image.

please let me know how to use `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2`

**Code**:

```
//use createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2
fgmask = new Mat();
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(30, 16, false);
bgs.apply(mMatInputFrame,fgmask,0);

//to display the mask
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.mMatInputFrame.cols(), this.mMatInputFrame.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(this.fgmask, bitmap);
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
mIVEdges.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you moving the camera?

Comment: yes..and would you please tell me why asked this question??does it matter??

Comment: Yes. If the background is changing (because you're moving the camera) than background subtraction won't work! Static background is mandatory for it to work correctly

Comment: Try leaving your phone still on a table, you'll see that this is working. As soon as you move it, then all white foreground ;D

Comment: @Miki ok i kept my phone still on a table but still no new results, i am still getting the white image...what should i use for removing the background from frames retrieved by Camera?

Comment: Background subtraction won't work for non-static background. So you'd better forget this approach, and start with detecting whatever you're trying to find in your images.

Answer (score 0):

As @Miki says, you cannot use this method if your background is not static.

`BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` uses Gaussian Mixture Model to model the background, so it can adapt to minor changes on it (illumination, new static objects, etc), but it cannot adapt to a fully dynamic background.

But if you still want to try it, here is how you can use it:

```
public class MOG2Subtractor {

    private final static double LEARNING_RATE = 0.01;

    private BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog;
    private Mat foreground;

    public MOG2Subtractor() {
        mog = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
        foreground = new Mat();
        // You can configure some parameters. For example:
        mog.setDetectShadows(false);
    }

    public Mat process(Mat inputImage) {
        mog.apply(inputImage, foreground, LEARNING_RATE);
        return foreground;
    }
}
```

Here you have all the parameters and their meaning: [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html)

Comment: i tried your exaample, and i am still getting only a white forground

Comment: Here I have an example app that implements four background subtraction algorithms (MOG2 included): [BackgroundSub](https://github.com/davidmigloz/go-bees-prototypes/tree/master/2_BackgroundSub). Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. (only display gray screen)

My problem was that I created new BackgroundSubctractorMOG2 object EVERY frame.

So initialization of the object should be before while loop.

below is not working code but for your easy understanding of what I mean above.

```
// ### PLACE HERE! ###
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

while(true) {
    // ### NOT HERE! ###
    //BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    fgmask = new Mat();
    bgs.apply(inputFrame, fgmask);
    // mat to bitmap and so on ..
}
```